# Cloudflare blocks CORS request

Tags: javascript, cloudflare

I created a rule on my API from Cloudflare so that if the same user tried to access it 3 times in 1 minute, Cloudflare should reply with captcha challenge.

It works very smooth with Postman but when I tried it from the browser it works when I am not blocked but when I get blocked the CORS options request gets blocked which might seem fine but my issue is that I need to check on the status of the response from my code and I can’t do this unless the CORS request passes then the actual one is blocked.

Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: Can you change the CORS headers in cloudflare?